# Would the division between a integer and 10^n result in inexact values?

Tags: javascript, numbers, division

Dose the division between a integer and 10^n result the exact value?
Beside, the integer is safe number in javascript and isn't express as "scientific counting" like 2.3e+1

I am dealing with the minus between two numbers.

I know the number with float will cause the wrong result such as `798 - 798 * 0.9 = 79.79999999999995`

So I found the solution as bellow and wonder if the integer (which is safe) do the division with the 10^n would result in the inexact values.

Dose this method hava any problems?

```
function minus(num1, num2) {
  const num1Digits = (num1.toString().split('.')[1] || '').length;
  const num2Digits = (num2.toString().split('.')[1] || '').length;
  const baseNum = Math.pow(10, Math.max(num1Digits, num2Digits));
  return (num1 * baseNum - num2 * baseNum) / baseNum; // is this ok?
}
```

Comment: Um, isnt that just `num1 - num2` ?

Comment: It results in inexact values anyway because it’s represented with powers of 2 internally, but the default decimal string representation of the closest base-2 value to your division by a power of 10 will be the value you expect, yes.

Comment: you state "the integer is safe number in javascript and isn't express as "scientific counting" like 2.3e+1", but I think you are mistaken.  According to MDN, all JavaScript numbers are stored as double precision floating point values and "There is no specific type for integers".

Comment: @DDupont Sorry for my misleading expression. Numbers in javascript have some display forms such as integer like `100`, scientific counting like `2.2e-7` and decimal like `7.99` . And yes, they are stored as double precision floating point values. In my case, I want to limit the input params for the `minus` method, which means `num1` and `num2` `toString()` won't be the scientific counting like `"2.2e-7"`.